# String to Integer (atoi) max integer problem in Swift

Tags: swift, int

The logic in my code working as I have passed 1000 of the trials in leetcode, but when the input "20000000000000000000" is plugged in my program returns 0 even though I have the following code.

```
let MAX: Int = 2147483647
let MIN: Int = -2147483648

if answer > MAX { return MAX }
if answer < MIN { return MIN }
```

I do not understand why my code can not handle that particular input as it can handle any number below that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Tell us more.  How does the input get used by your program?

Answer (score 0):

You're overflowing the limits of an `Int` with a value such as `20000000000000000000`. Therefore (and this is an assumption as you haven't provided the code where `answer` is set a value), if `answer` is set from the value of `atoi("20000000000000000000")`, `answer` will never be greater than `2147483647` or less than `-2147483648` as a signed `Int` can't hold values past this range. It'll instead come out as a number somewhere within that range, which is the 0 you're seeing and therefore never meets the condition to return either `MAX` or `MIN`.

Therefore, to improve this, you could begin by using `strtol` instead of `atoi` which returns a `signed long` rather than a `signed int`. This gives you a larger data size for comparisons sake and you can then revert to checking string length to reject strings for more characters (digits) than in the `MAX` or `MIN` values.

`strtol` function signature is: `strtol(__str: UnsafePointer<Int8>!, __endptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>!, __base: Int32)`

Which can be used in the following:

```
let input = "20000000000000000000"

let MAX: Int = 2147483647
let MIN: Int = -2147483648

if input.count > 11 && input.hasPrefix("-") {
    return MIN
}
else if input.count > 10 {
    return MAX
}

let answer = strtol(input, nil, 0)

if answer > MAX { return MAX }
if answer < MIN { return MIN }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I appreciate it a ton, thanks.

Comment: @Gianmarco no worries, if this has resolved your issue don’t forget to mark as accepted answer so the question can be closed off.